# How to fix error with negative value being passed to LEFT()

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following is designed to extract the first chars from a string. In this case extracting the area from a postcode. As the area may be variable length (1 or 2 chars) the rule is get the first alpha characters, before the numbers in the first half of the string (delimited by a space).

If the string is formatted correctly, the following works. However, if the string is malformed (as demonstrated below) the PATINDEX returns 0, which in turn results in -1 being passed back to the parent LEFT().

How can I trap the negative value and substitute the -1 with a 0?

Malformations could take the format:
'ABO 12BT', 'AB012BT' etc.

```sql
DECLARE @Postcode nVARCHAR (10) = 'ab124th'
(   
    SELECT
        RTRIM
            (  
                LEFT
                    (
                        LEFT
                            (
                                @Postcode, CHARINDEX(' ', @Postcode)
                            ),
                            (
                                PATINDEX
                                    (
                                        '%[0-9]%', 
                                        LEFT
                                            (
                                                @Postcode,
                                                CHARINDEX(' ', @Postcode)
                                            )            
                                    ) -1
                            )
                    )                         
            )
)
```

Comment: `isnull(nullif(..., -1), 0)`?

Comment: That's it! Please submit as an answer for me to accept. Kind regards.

Comment: Just curious, why doing it so complicated by looking for the space? Wouldn't something like `RTRIM(LEFT(@Postcode, 2))` be enough?

Comment: No, because UK postcodes are inherently tricky to split up into components. Here are some examples of area codes : 'SW1W 0NY' = 'SW', 'L1 8JQ' = 'L', 'PO16 7GZ' = 'PO' and there are some really nasty legacy codes and 'odd' codes. The system has evolved and follows some quite disjointed rules. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom

Comment: Many UK postcode 'rules' are then negated by a whole load of 'exceptions'!

Answer (score 1):

`isnull(nullif(patnidex(...) - 1, -1), 0)`